# server side clearing unwanted connection before closing socket

Tags: c++, sockets

in a c++ server code, I need to close sockets when a first read doesn't began with expected chars:

```
char buff_truc[4] = {0};
read(mysock, buff_truc, sizeof buff_truc) ;
if ( memcmp( buff_truc, "TRUC", 4 ) != 0 ) {
    close(mysock);
}
```

It's asked to me to read the whole content of available incoming data to ignore them before closing.

I tried something like

```
char buff[8] = {0};
do { 
    lu = read( mysock, buff, sizeof buff); 
} while (lu > 0);
```

but it waits for socket timeout to tell me it reads zero byte

Comment: Hmm? You don't have to read data from a socket before closing it. What's the point of doing that? I'm not sure I understand. The first snippet should be fine (except I would use `std::string` and `==` instead of `memcmp`).

Comment: the big boss tells to do like this.... he suspects something wrong on client side if we close immediatly. I found the call to 'shutdown( ) ' before 'close()' is much more violent !

Comment: I have no idea how reading all the data helps client. Actually this is very insecure approach because malicious client will be able to keep your server busy indefinitely (by pushing data into the socket in a loop). Please, try to convince the big boss that he should debug the client without modyfing the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not really concern about the data which you received.( Received buffer not start with "TRUC" ). You can close the socket.

> I tried something like

Is you have tried in client side before closing socket only ?

Comment: I'm only coding the server-side.

Comment: Fine. If you dont bother about data which not starts with your specified sequence. You can close the socket.